# Disjunctive graphs of job-shop scheduling problems

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Would anybody help me with drawing the following graph in TikZ?
[image]

I started with something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[  ->,  >=Stealth,  shorten >=1pt,  auto,  node distance=2cm,  thick,  main node/.style={circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}  ]

  % Nodes
  \node[main node] (b) at (0,0) {b};
  
  \node[main node] (7) at (2,2) {7};
  \node[main node] (4) at (2,0) {4};
  \node[main node] (1) at (2,-2) {1};
  
  \node[main node] (8) at (4,2) {8};
  \node[main node] (5) at (4,0) {5};
  \node[main node] (2) at (4,-2) {2};
  
  \node[main node] (9) at (6,2) {9};
  \node[main node] (6) at (6,0) {6};
  \node[main node] (3) at (6,-2) {3};

  \node[main node] (e) at (8,0) {e};

  % Solid edges
  \draw (b) -- (1);
  \draw (b) -- (4);
  \draw (b) -- (7);
  
  \draw (1) -- (4);
  \draw (2) -- (5);
  \draw (3) -- (6);
  
  \draw (4) -- (7);
  \draw (5) -- (8);
  \draw (6) -- (9);
  
  \draw (7) -- (e);
  \draw (8) -- (e);
  \draw (9) -- (e);

  % Dashed edges
  \draw[dashed] (1) -- (8);
  \draw[dashed] (8) -- (1);
  \draw[dashed] (2) -- (3);
  
  \draw[dashed] (4) -- (5);
  \draw[dashed] (5) -- (6);
  
  \draw[dashed] (7) -- (8);
  \draw[dashed] (8) -- (9);
  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it is very time consuming to get it finished following the available documentation. Thank you (the thin arrows you can see in the picture can be dashed, as suggested in the code snippet).

Comment: Welcome! The squiggly lines you will have to figure out manually. TikZ can't find a nice path through a bunch of nodes. But the regular placement can be automated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a start on placing the nodes and connecting them with values in two loops.

For this, the `chains` library helps in placing and connecting nodes in a regular fashion. Their distance apart is given via `node distance`.

The `0` node is placed to the left of the middle of the west side of the nodes 1/3 and 1/4 so that it is placed vertically centered.

Finally, I've added some simple connections between the existing nodes via the `graph` syntax/library.

### Code

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, calc, graphs, quotes, shapes.multipart}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance=1cm,
      all nodes/.style={shape=circle, draw, minimum size=1cm},
      node BF/.style 2 args={
        all nodes, node other/.code=,shape=circle,
        name=#1 #2,node contents=$#1_{#2}$},
      node 7/.style={node BF={B}{#1}}, node 8/.style={node BF={F}{#1}},
      node other/.style 2 args={
        all nodes, shape=circle solidus, inner sep=.1em, name=#1 #2,
        node contents={#2 \nodepart{lower} #1}},
      >=Latex, every join/.style={->},
      start chain=rows going below,
    ]
    \foreach[count=\rowi] \rows in {{1, 3, 6, 7, 3, 6, -33},
                                    {8, 5, 10, 10, 10, 4, -61},
                                    {5, 4, 8, 9, 1, 7, -44},
                                    {5, 5, 5, 3, 8, 9, -45},
                                    {9, 3, 5, 4, 3, 1, -32},
                                    {3, 3, 9, 10, 4, 1, -39}}{
      \node[on chain, node other=\rowi 1];
      \tikzset{start branch={row\rowi} going right}
      \foreach[count=\coli from 2] \elem in \rows 
        \node[on chain, node \coli/.try=\rowi,
                        node other=\rowi\coli, join=by "$\elem$"];
    }
    \node[all nodes, left=2cm of $(3 1.west)!.5!(4 1.west)$](0){$0$}
      foreach \rowi in {1, ..., 6}{
        (0) edge[every join, "0" sloped] (\rowi\space 1)};
    
    \path[dashed] graph[edges=every join, use existing nodes]{
      1 1 ->[bend left]  3 1 ->[bend left]  5 1,
      2 1 ->[bend right] 4 1 ->[bend right] 6 1
    };
    \foreach \up/\Row/\above/\rows in {+/1/above/{1,2,3}, -/6/below/{6,5,4}}
      \foreach[count=\i from 0] \row in \rows
        \draw[rounded corners, every join] (0)
          |- node[at end, \above] {$0$} ([shift={(0,\up 1)}]B \Row.center)
          to[out=0, in/.evaluated={\up(\i==0?135:60)}, out looseness={1+1.5*sign(\i)}](F \row);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is precisely what I need. Is it hard to sketch a bended arrow connecting the encircled zero to, say F_1, as suggested by the original picture? Thank you.

Comment: @Jorge.Squared I've adjusted the code so that it fully uses the `chains` library for both directions (chain for the rows and a branch for each row). I've also added the long arrows to the `F` nodes.